# SQL Find dynamic column and update value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
##tblReports - temporary table

Books| GroupId | Category | 01-01-2014 | 02-01-2014 | ..etc
----------+------------+--------------------------
100  | 1       | Limit    | 700         | 0
100  | 1       | Exp      | 70          | 0
100  | 1       | Balance  | 630         | 0
200  | 1       | Limit    | 0           | 900
200  | 1       | Exp      | 0           | 100
200  | 1       | Balance  | 0           | 800


tblLimits -user table

GroupId | 100BooksLimit | 200BooksLimit
----------+------------+---------------
1       | 700           | 900
2       | 7             | 10
```

Desired output

```
Books| GroupId | Category | 01-01-2014 | 02-01-2014
----------+------------+--------------------------
100  | 1       | Limit    | 700         | 700
100  | 1       | Exp      | 70          | 0
100  | 1       | Balance  | 630         | 700
200  | 1       | Limit    | 900         | 900
200  | 1       | Exp      | 0           | 100
200  | 1       | Balance  | 900         | 800
```

the 3rd column onwards from ##tblReports are dynamic. Can you help me how to update it?

Basically:

1. find all the columns with 0 values
2. search for its limit in tblLimits table using GroupId and Books.
3. get the limit and update 'Limit' and 'Balance' row

I tried to use dynamic queries but I cant make it work. Please help me

*I know the design of the tables are not ideal and follow the best practices as this is a client requirement that I need to follow. This is a temporary table and a lot of things happened before this table (multiple joins, pivot and un-pivot)

tables shown are simplified and does not exactly replicate the actual table. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use dynamic queries but I cant make it work -->Can you post that query in the question?

Comment: maybe you should starts from the begining. How do you create that `##tblReports` ?

Comment: @squirrel, thats a very long query lots of pivot un pivoting involved.

Comment: why not get the data required correct in the first place rather than patch it at the later stage. It might be easier to settle in that stage. The data you need to patch is column wise and the column name is dynamic and there are multiple columns right ? That doesn't sounds like an easy task.

Comment: Like I said, before this table was built a lot pivoting and unpivoting happened. I tried your suggestion before posting here and it didnt work yet. If I posted it here its going to be messy and lot of explanation required.

Comment: the real table that im working on right now does not look like this. this is very simplified version of the real table

Comment: the col [02-01-2014]-row book100 is supposed not to be there for group1 book100. the reason it was there because of the pivot. see book200 of the same group. I hope you get my point. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Create temp tables and sample data
CREATE TABLE ##tblReports (books INT, groupid INT, category VARCHAR(25), [01-01-2014] INT, [02-01-2014] INT)
INSERT INTO ##tblReports VALUES (100, 1, 'Limit', 700, 0), (100, 1, 'Exp', 70, 0), (100, 1, 'Balance', 630, 0),
(200, 1, 'Limit', 0, 900), (200, 1, 'Exp', 0, 100), (200, 1, 'Balance', 0, 800)

CREATE TABLE ##tblLimits (groupid INT, [100bookslimit] INT, [200bookslimit] INT)
INSERT INTO ##tblLimits VALUES (1, 700, 900), (2, 7, 10)

-- Unpivot ##tblLimits in a CTE (see footnote for what this outputs)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = '
;WITH cte_unpivot AS
(
    SELECT groupid, val, CAST(REPLACE(col, ''bookslimit'', '''') AS INT) AS books
    FROM ##tblLimits
    UNPIVOT (val FOR col IN ('

-- Are the columns in ##tblLimits dynamic (other than groupid)? If so, get their 
-- names from tempdb.sys.columns metadata.  
SELECT @sql += QUOTENAME(name) + ',' -- [Column],
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##tblLimits') AND name <> 'groupid'

-- Delete trailing comma
SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql) - 1) 

SELECT @sql +=  '))AS u
)
SELECT t.books, t.groupid, category, 
'

-- Get ##tblReports column names from tempdb.sys.columns metadata.
SELECT @sql += '
    CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = 0 AND t.category IN (''Limit'', ''Balance'') 
        THEN c.val ELSE t.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' END AS ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ','
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##tblReports') AND name NOT IN ('books', 'groupid', 'category')

-- Delete trailing comma again
SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql) - 1) 

SELECT @sql += '
FROM ##tblReports t
LEFT JOIN cte_unpivot c ON t.books = c.books AND t.groupid = c.groupid
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Returns:

```
books   groupid category    01-01-2014  02-01-2014
100     1       Limit       700         700
100     1       Exp         70          0
100     1       Balance     630         700
200     1       Limit       900         900
200     1       Exp         0           100
200     1       Balance     900         800
```

The key is unpivoting ##tblLimits into this format so you can easily join it to ##tblReports:

```
groupid val books
1       700 100
1       900 200
2       7   100
2       10  200
```

Here's the SQL it generates (but formatted):

```
;WITH cte_unpivot 
     AS (SELECT groupid, 
                val, 
                Cast(Replace(col, 'bookslimit', '') AS INT) AS books 
         FROM   ##tbllimits 
                UNPIVOT (val 
                        FOR col IN ([100bookslimit], 
                                    [200bookslimit]))AS u) 
SELECT t.books, 
       t.groupid, 
       category, 
       CASE 
         WHEN [01-01-2014] = 0 
              AND t.category IN ( 'Limit', 'Balance' ) THEN c.val 
         ELSE t.[01-01-2014] 
       END AS [01-01-2014], 
       CASE 
         WHEN [02-01-2014] = 0 
              AND t.category IN ( 'Limit', 'Balance' ) THEN c.val 
         ELSE t.[02-01-2014] 
       END AS [02-01-2014] 
FROM   ##tblreports t 
       LEFT JOIN cte_unpivot c 
              ON t.books = c.books 
                 AND t.groupid = c.groupid
```